# Can a strained diamond actually become conductive?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory, diamond

According to about.com,

> "The electrical resistivity of most diamonds is on the order of 10<sup>11</sup> to 10<sup>18</sup> Ω·m" ([source](http://chemistry.about.com/od/geochemistry/f/Is-Diamond-A-Conductor.htm))

However, according to the diamond band diagram, it seems that under a certain range of tensile strain, a diamond becomes conductive, since its band gap vanishes:

[image: Energy bands for diamond versus lattice constant . One atomic unit equals 1 Rydberg = 13.6 eV.] ([source](http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/ecen3320/newbook/chapter2/ch2_3.htm))

Is it actually possible to achieve this situation?

Comment: If I understand the article correctly this is a calculated band structure. There is no way to achieve this effect in diamond because it would fracture long before the C-C distance became large enough to merge the bands.

Comment: @JohnRennie, can you post your comment as an answer? I would like to expand it with additional info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum you can strain silicon, for example, before crystalline defects are introduced is ~1%, at which point the conductivity would go down. In the diamond case, the diagram indicates that you’d have to strain it by 200% (i.e. the atoms would have to be spaced twice as far apart as their equilibrium distance) to have no bandgap.  This would be far too energetically unfavourable to happen.  The material would break apart or be extremely defective well before this amount of strain is reached.

In other words (@JohnRennie), since **this is a calculated band structure**, there is no way to achieve this effect in diamond because it would fracture long before the C-C distance became large enough to merge the bands

Carbon can be very conductive (some forms of carbon nanotubes for example are metallic), but carbon in these forms is definitely not diamond.

Comment: If you're not only interested in *pure* diamonds, you may find it interesting that boron-doped diamonds are [semiconducting at room temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_properties_of_diamond#Electrical_properties), and even becomes [superconducting near the absolute zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covalent_superconductor#Diamond).